# Some doubts about interpretation of an atomic formula in predicate calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have some doubt related to the interpretation of atomics formulas in predicate calculus.

**In predicate calculus a formula will be interpreted on a specific domain that is where I take the allowed values for the formula constants.**

So I have a formula **A** such that:

**$\{p_1,.....,p_n\}$**: is the set of all the predicates into the A formula.

**$\{t_1,.....,t_k\}$**: is the set of all the constants that appear in the n predicates

So an **interpretation** of my A formula is a triad build in this way:

**$I = \{D, \{R_1,....,R_n\}, \{d_1,....,d_k\}\}$** where:

1) **$D$: is a not empty domain** (so the constants are in $D$)

2) **$R_i$ represents an assignment of a relation $n$-ary that goes in D (in a valid constant) for each p_i predicate**

3) **$d_i$: represents an assignment of a $d_j$ element, that belong to $D$, for each constant $a_j$** (this thing say also that a constant symbol of my language must be a value that is in the domain $D$)

So for example if I have this formula:
[image]

A valid interpretation for the previous formula could be:

[image]

In which I say that:

1) **The domain D is all the Natural Number set**

2) **The relation associated to the p predicate is the minor or equal relation**

3) **The value of the constant a must be into the domain D and is the natural number 0**

And this is true because this say that in the natural number set exist a special element that is 0 that is the minimum element of the set

Is my reasoning correct until now? i hope yes...

Now I have a big doubt about the meaning of what on my book is called as **INTERPRETATION OF ATOMICS FORMULA**.

It say that give an atomic formula its interpretation is:

[image] if  it is **TRUE** that: [image] and **FALSE otherwise**

I have some problem to unserstand what means this assertion.

I think that **$P_i$ is a predicate that is into the set of the predicates of my language: **$\{p_1,.....,p_n\}$**

but what is $a_1,...,a_n$ ? I think that are the constants used in this predicate.

I am not understanding what it means.

Someone can help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to start from scratch because your post is very long.

Let us start with a language 
$$
L=\{R_i \,:\, i\in I\}\cup\{f_j \,:\, i\in J\}\cup \{c_k\, :\, k\in K\}
$$
The $R_i$ are relation symbols, the $f_j$ function symbols and the $c_k$ constant symbols with $I,J,K$ indexing sets. Now an interpretation/structure/model for this language is a tuple
$$
\mathfrak{A}=\langle A,\{\textbf{R}_i \,:\, i\in I\},\{\textbf{f}_j \,:\, i\in J\}, \{\textbf{c}_k\, :\, k\in K\}\rangle$$
Where $A$ is a (depending on your conventions, possibly required to be non-empty) set, if the symbol $R_i$ is $n$-ary then the corresponding $\textbf{R}_i\subseteq A^n$. If the symbol $f_j$ is $n$-ary then the corresponding $\textbf{f}_j$ is a function $A^n\rightarrow A$ and $\textbf{c}_j\in A$.

The idea of this is that you just interpret a relation symbol as a relation on the domain, a function symbol as a function and a constant symbol as an element. Now we can use this to define a satisfaction relation on the formulae in the language $L$. But we have to be careful as we may have free-variables in the formula.

So inductively, let $i:\{\text{variables}\}\rightarrow A$. Then inductively we define an interpretation of terms, and use this to do formulae.
$$
c_i^\mathfrak{A}=\textbf{c}_i
$$
$$
x_i^\mathfrak{A}=i(x_i)
$$
$$
f_i(t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_n)^\mathfrak{A}=\textbf{f}_i(t_1^\mathfrak{A},t_2^\mathfrak{A},\ldots,t_n^\mathfrak{A})$$
So the idea of this definition is that we find out the value of a term by evaluating any constants or variables according to $i$ and the structure $\mathfrak{A}$ and then apply functions as defined in the structure. Now we are ready to define satisfaction of an atomic.

Atomic formulas look like $t_1=t_2$ where $t_i$ are terms or like $R(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ where $R$ is an $n$-ary relation symbol and $t_i$ are terms. We define
$$
(\mathfrak{A},i)\models t_1=t_2 \Leftrightarrow t_1^\mathfrak{A}=t_2^\mathfrak{A}
$$
and
$$
(\mathfrak{A},i)\models R(t_1,\ldots,t_n) \Leftrightarrow \langle t_1,\ldots,t_n\rangle\in \textbf{R}
$$

So we say that a claim that $t_i=t_j$ is true if they are interpreted as the same object in the domain, and a claim that a relation $R$ holds of some $n$-tuple of terms if we have stipulated that the interpretation of the terms are in the domain of $\textbf{R}$.

Hope this clears a few things up.

Comment: It might be even more suggestive if you write $R^{\mathfrak{A}}$ instead of bold $R$, to match the notation for terms.